# Sum Function with division

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out which is the correct format when using the sum function with division:

Which one is correct?

```
sum(filesize/1024)
```

or

```
sum(filesize)/1024
```

The filesize column is a measurement in kilobytes which I am converting to megabytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They mean different things.  `sum(filesize/1024)` reduces the file size to megabytes, and then sums megabytes.  For each file, this "forgets" the size in excess of the megabytes boundary, so it will underreport the total file size.

`sum(filesize)/1024` will report the correct size in megabytes-- rounded down.

Comment: +1: beat me to it. Also, there is a slight performance advantage to only performing the division once after the sum rather than on every element.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd go with option #2 (assuming the number's aren't so large you'll have overflow issues to deal with).  This way the numbers stay as exact as possible until they're given to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the first one is correct - sum(filesize/1024), but you'll want to make sure that filesize is never 0, or your query will error.

Use decode on oracle or if on SQL server to do that.

Comment: You only get an error when the divisor is zero, but here it's a constant 1024.

Comment: Why would 0 cause an error? Dividing by 0 is impossible, dividing 0 is trivial ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Logically, both should give the same result.  However, **sum(filesize)/1024** will probably be faster.  If you go with the other option, you're performing the divide operation on each result, instead of just doing it once.